# How do I get rid of the persistent dock in Pop!_OS?

Tags: gnome, pop-os, dock, plank

I used to use dash-to-dock as my daily driver now, I tried switching to plank but whenever I open the activities menu I see another dock at the left of my screen(even after I disable the dash-to-dock gnome extension). I tried installing the vanilla-gnome-desktop but that too has that dock at the side. Is there any way of getting rid of that dock?

Answer (score 2):

Well after some research on reddit I figured the dock at the side is actually called a dash. You can install an extension called just perfection from gnome extensions website which allows you to disable the dash altogether. Here disabling means to just hide the dash and nothing more.